# I am using jQuery to post a php file, I am getting 500 internal server file, Why?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, validation, phpass

I am building a jQuery file to validate user input for login on a wordpress site.  I have made functions to check the wordpress database for usernames, emails, and passwords.  I have the functions working perfectly for usernames and emails, however with the password function I get a 500 internal server error.  The only thing I can think of that would be causing this would be my trying to include three files from wordpress.  I have to use the class-phpass.php to check the passwords as the passwords are hashed and then stored into the database.  The class-phpass.php file has a function called CheckPassword which compares a hashed password with the plain text password, then returns true if they match, false if they do not.  I have also included the wp-settings.php and wp-load.php, just trying to get my php file to work for my validation.

I am creating this so that users will not be taken away from my login in lightbox if they type in a wrong username or password.

This is my jQuery function to check the password:

```
jQuery.post("/wp-content/themes/Landing/includes/check_password.php", {password:pWd2, email:email},
            function(data){
                if( data == '1' )
                {
                    CheckPassword = true;
                }else{
                    //show that the password is NOT available
                    alert("The password and/or username you have entered is incorrect!");
                    CheckPassword = false;
                }  
            });
```

UPDATE!!!::

Ok, I got my php file working like it should, and my jQuery.post is working as it should. I am having a logic error now, however.   I am using chrome tools and stepping through the code, I need to return false to the form to keep the webpage from refreshing/redirecting.  It seems to  step through the function(data) after submitting for the check I have in place here:

```
if (CheckUsername == false){
        return false;
    }
    if (CheckPassword == false){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
```

it checks ^  ^ that block of code before stepping into the post function and setting CheckPassword to false if password is incorrect.

Comment: what do you get if you put '/wp-content/themes/Landing/includes/check_password.php in your browser? any php errors (Make sure error reporting is on)

Comment: I get a blank white page

Comment: my check_username.php gives me a 0

Comment: Id expect an error if there was something wrong, so if error logging is on then maybe not, if you put echo "here"; on the line above "$connection = " etc do you see it when you manually go to the page?

Comment: I see the echo statement, I did have to change my includes statements they were breaking the page.  However, after fixing those, deleted the 'echo "here";' and retesting, I still am not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This line is supposed to establish a connection to your database:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("databaseAddress", "login", "password", "table"); //creates a database connection
```

"`DatabaseAddress`" isn't a valid database address, and the other options probably aren't either. You have to fill out those credentials.
When using Wordpress, some constants are defined in `wp-config.php`. Try this line:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); //creates a database connection
```

Comment: Sorry, I do know that, I changed that information so I wouldn't be giving out the database creds to everyone :) my fault I should have made that clear

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. I will delete this answer in 15 minutes, please make sure that you correct your post, or someone else will notice that as well ;)